# ionic2 push notification API taking a long time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

In an Ionic2 project that I am working on I have configured the Ionic Push Cloud service. When I use the ionic.io dashboard to send a push notification, the notification registers on the target device immediately.

When I now use the ionic http push API to programmatically deploy the push notification, the push takes a few hours to register on my target device. Is this expected behavior? If not how can we reduce the push timing to have push notifications go out in an instantaneous manner (within a minute or two?).

**Of note:** A week or two ago I had also tested the http push API and observed instantaneous push notifications to my target device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could have been a possible [outage](http://status.ionicframework.com/). Does the issue still persist?

Push notifications are expected to be instant or near-instant most of the time. I suppose your case on that day could have been affected by smaller undocumented backend procedures, like migration or maintenance of some sort, which is why your notifications.were not lost, but late.

Comment: I have just tested the http push API again today and now it appears to be registering the push notification on the target device instantaneously; which is the desired result. Checking the ionic services page link (outages above) it does not appear that the push service was out at all on the date where I experienced hour-long delays (7/7/17). This concerns me as I'm still not sure why the issue occurred or if it is even an issue or possibly an expected behavior for Ionic Push.

Comment: That's what I expected. :) Push notifications are expected to be instant or near-instant most of the time. I suppose your case on that day could have been affected by smaller undocumented backend procedures, like migration or maintainance of some sort, which is why your notifications.were not lost, but late. If you feel that your question is covered, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Could you add you explanation above to the answer? I feel that your comment above more appropriately answered my question.